# C++ version of isnormal()

Tags: c++, floating-point, numbers

Is there a C++ version of the isnormal, isnan and so C functions? I know I can use the C functions from C++, but I'm always interested to know if there are some C++-only alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as far as I know.  Doesn't look like there's one in the STL.  Since that's such a simple function I would guess they didn't want to take the time to replace it.  The old C version works fine.  I would say just continue to use the C isnormal().

Answer (score 5):

They're included in `<cmath>` in the C++0x draft:

```
template <class T> int fpclassify(T x);
template <class T> bool isfinite(T x);
template <class T> bool isinf(T x);
template <class T> bool isnan(T x);
template <class T> bool isnormal(T x);
```

Comment: Have they been included in the published version of the standard?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such a functionality in stl.
You could check that in reference:
[cppreference](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/)

C functionalities was placed in C++ and APIs are available through
headers without postfix "*.h" and with prefix "c"
example

```
<cstdlib>
```

But I'm certain You know about it.

If You're looking for something simmilar you probably would find many C like functions in amazing **boost** library. Most of classes would be introduced to new C++ standard so its worth to learn.

[boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0)

Comment: Maybe not. You (http://stackoverflow.com/users/147845/you) seems to prefer PHP and Web based questions.